# I want to show assigned users using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to show assigned users to the user I have made relationship b/w user and user_permission  but I am facing an error.how to fix it thanks. please check this error https://flareapp.io/share/q5Y12O5X#F52 Can anyone provide me a solution that where I am wrong.

Database table

```
            user_permission table 
            please see here https://ibb.co/7486n95     

            user table 
            please see here https://ibb.co/5jmqb0H
```

**Controller**

```
           public function index()
          {
          $users=User::with('permission')->where('id' ,'!=' ,Auth::id())->paginate(6);   
          return view('index',compact('users'));
           }
```

**User Model**

```
            class User extends Authenticatable
            {
            public function permission()
            {   
            return $this- 
            >hasMany('App\Users_permissions','user_Access_id','id');
            }
            }
```

**Users_permissions Model**

```
           class Users_permissions extends Model
           {

           protected $table = 'user_permission';
           protected $fillable = ['id','user_id', 'user_Access_id'];
           public function user()
           {
           return $this->belongsTo('App\User','id');
           }
           }
```

**Html View**

```
        <!-- Default box -->
        <div class="card card-solid">
        <div class="card-body pb-0">
        <div class="row d-flex align-items-stretch">
        @foreach($users->permission as $user)
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 ">
        <div class="card bg-light">
        <div class="card-header text-muted border-bottom-0">
       <div class="card-tools"> <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="3 New Messages" 
       class="badge badge-primary"></span>
       </div>
       </div>
       <div class="card-body pt-0">
       <div class="row">
       <div class="col-7">
       <h2 class="lead"><b>{{$user->name}}</b></h2>
       <p class="text-muted text-sm"><b>Job: </b> {{$user->job}}</p>
       <ul class="ml-4 mb-0 fa-ul text-muted">
       <li class="small"><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-lg fa-phone"></i></span> Phone 
       #: {{$user->phone_number}}</li>
       </ul>
       </div>
      <div class="col-5 text-center">
      <img src="{{url('public/assets/dist/img/user1-128x128.jpg')}}" alt="" class="img- 
      circle img-fluid">
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
      <div class="text-left">
       @if($user->isOnline())
      <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> Online</a>@else
      <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-circle text-default"></i> offline</a>@endif</div>
      <div class="text-right">
      <a href="{{url('/chat',$user->id)}}" class="btn btn-sm bg-teal"> <i class="fas fa- 
      comments"></i><b> Chat</b>
      </a>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>@endforeach</div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.card-body -->
     <div class="card-footer">
     <nav aria-label="Contacts Page Navigation">
     <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
     <li>{{$users->links()}}</li>
     </ul>
     </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- /.card-footer -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.card -->
```

Comment: You are not getting permission data in $users variable that is why you are getting this error here @foreach($users->permission as $user)

Comment: How can I resolve this issue only want to show assigned users example, user, no 8 is login and admin has assigned 5,6,7 user to 8 id how to show this?

Comment: You cannot use comma separated FKs. Each FK should have its own row.

Comment: It seems your database structure is not correct. You cannot perform relation using comma separated values using Foreign key.  Also please share the value of $users variable

Answer (score 0):

Here, what you are trying to do this is you are directly accessing `permission` relationship from collection, this is why it is showing error. First you have to loop through users and inside that particular user permission relationship exist. So you have to loop through users model first.

Hope this helps:)

Answer (score 0):

You are applying `permissions` to the collection of users, but only an individual user has permissions. You need to loop through all of your users, then access the users permissions:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
  ...
  @foreach($user->permission as $permission)
    {{$permission->name}}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Actually I have used this code but the page is showing empty thanks.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the log file to see any errors.